# "Dead-letter" messages in deleted queue in RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I asked a question with similar architecture here: [RabbitMQ sends message from one queue to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74738761/rabbitmq-sends-message-from-one-queue-to-another)

But I'll write it here again anyway.

I have a chat application that uses RabbitMQ for the communication between servers. I'm using Consistent Hash Exchange to make sure that one message for a particular user will go to the same queue. And for one queue there is at most one consumer for that queue, hence ensuring message ordering. This means every consumer will create its own unique queue (auto-delete) and bind the newly created queue to the consistent hash exchange.

The problem is, when consumers die, maybe because of lost connection to the broker or any other reasons, the queue is gone, and unprocessed messages inside the queue is gone as well.

Is it possible to "dead-letter" those unprocessed messages? Or is there any better solutions?